How to use `polars` in a Node.js project initiated with Vite?
polars has two libraries for the browser side and server side. However, I'm unable to follow their examples to get both to work. (One post related to this here on Stackoverflow is one: No loader is configured for ".node" files)
I'd like to ask how to use polars in a Node.js project initiated with Vite, e.g. using import polars as pl from 'polars' in a script.js/main.js file.

Not sure I understand the exact problem: both links show you how their respective import statements work, and if you're trying to get it to run in the browser, then you import and use the browser version, not the server version, so the question is: are you trying to get polars to run as part of your client bundle, or are you trying to run it server-side as part of some API route handling?

You need plugins to load the .node files with vite. Basically, you need to tell vite to ignore the .node file and then copy it over manually to your output directory at the end.
We did this specifically for nodejs-polars and documented how it was achieved in the this article.

The plugin detects when rollup attempts to load a .node file and returns a snippet of code instead. This snippet requires the .node file at runtime, expecting it to be beside the bundle itself.

It boils down to

Rewrite the code to import the .node file
Put the .node file beside the output bundle
Rewrite all imports of the .node files so that they point to the files that are beside the bundle

Hope this helps!

nodejs-polars is a server side library for Node, Bun or Deno.
You will not be able to load it into a Vite based web app.
